What are the different ways to manage and organize wires?
When I say manage and organize, i do mean in the sense of grouping wires together. For example, if i have 2 wires going to a light, then grouping them together seems like the best thing to do to keep everything organized. Something i had realized while writing the question, is that there is no best way to do what i said, i feel like it is a case by case type of thing, with some methods being preferred in certain situations. Here some ways ive found are:

Zip ties, which are simple and can keep wires somewhat together, but don't create and obvious link between the wires.

wire wrapping tape, seem to be a good option since it makes it clear that whatever is under the tape goes to the same place at least but style wise, i wouldn't put it too high and it seems like something that gets used up very quickly

big heat shrink tubes, seem like a really neat and elegant way of keep wires together, but same as the tape feels like something that gets used up quick and on top of that, also requires good memory to remember to put it on before you connect the wires


Please share your favorite ways and what are the pros/cons of them?

You're likely to run into a closing of this question. SE is not a discussion forum, but an question/answer resource. Asking opinions is specifically contraindicated.
Consider to create/edit to focus on a specific problem to be solved.
